# Drupalgap geofield error

Tags: json, drupal-7

Ok I have a problem. How can I edit the Json string that drupalgap sends out to my drupal site?
My problem is that I use geoJson widget type for my website which is not supported in DrupalGap geoField module so I need to improvise.

Drupalgap is sending:

```
{"title":"sdf","type":"problem","language":"und","body":{"und":[{"value":"dsf"}]},"field_location":{"und":[{"value":"someValue"}]},"field_kategorija":{"und":{"value":"4"}}}
```

Everything in this json string gets nicely saved on my site except the field_location field. I think that if I coud change the string to:

```
"field_location":{"und":[{"geom":"someValue"}]}
```

my field_location would be saved in the database.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok here is the solution. I managed to change the json string but Jdrupal didnt let me send the string poping up errors. The only way to send the geofield value is with the geofield_latlon widget type. But here I also encountered a problem. 
In the official documentation the json string that is being pushed to the service is:

```
"field_location":{"und":[{"lat":"someLat", "lon": "someLon"}]}
```

This does not work, i had to change it to this format to get it to work:

```
"field_location":{"und":[ "geom": {"lat":"someLat", "lon": "someLon"}]}
```

Lost 6 hours on this :(

Comment: In the geofield module for DrupalGap, the geofield_assemble_form_state_into_field() function would need to be expanded to support your field's widget. That is the hook that is used to build the JSON string that is sent to the Drupal site.